# Can Doomsday be killed for good?

Tags: dc, doomsday

I'm not asking about the kind of killing where he comes back to life some time later, I'm talking about the kind of situation where one can say with 100% certainty that he will stay dead. The only method I can think of is killing him temporarily and then destroy his body to the point where there is nothing that could resurrect (probably this would entail disintegrating the entirety of his mass down to the molecular/atomic level).

Other than this, are there any in-universe mentions as to how to get rid of him for good?

Comment: No. No comic book character can be [killed for good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_death).

Comment: @Richard Except for ... some people who don't, which your cited article even mentions :P But since that list has grown shorter and shorter, maybe the last one remaining on it won't stay dead either....

Comment: @bmwurm - They brought back Bucky. And uncle Ben even appears in a few 'alt-universe' comics.

Comment: @Richard Yeah, and Jason T. as well. Heck they brought back Thomas Wayne in Flashpoint. The thing with Uncle Ben is a bit like with Gwen, it would probably be interesting to fint out who dies more often in how many universes, Ben or Gwen? MJ got really lucky she got named Mary-Jane and not xyz-Jen, or she'd be toast real quick :P

Comment: Dr. Ian Malcom: *Life will not be contained. Life breaks free, it expands to new territories and crashes through barriers, painfully, maybe even dangerously, but, uh... well, there it is. 
- I'm simply saying that life, uh... finds a way.*